# Power BI Desktop Odata data limit

Tags: odata, powerbi, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to get data to PowerBI Desktop via an OData endpoint. We have eight OData endpoints with authentication and this works fine.

[image]
[image]

But when the returned data volume is high from OData endpoints, I get the following error.

[image]

Notice the size of data retrieved from OData endpoints. For TransactionFacts, it's around 150MB and for AccountFacts it's around 177MB.

After some time, I get the error in Image 3.

I tried all the endpoints with Fiddler and all works fine (With Fildder, retrieved data size from AccountFacts was 185MB). These works with PowerBI too, if the data volume was a little less than this.

So my question is, is there a limitation of data volume which can be retrieved to PowerBI Desktop via OData endpoints? If so, what is the limit and what can I do to fix this problem.

Thank you.